# I want to interact smart contract with react native mobile application

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, web3js, moralis, wallet-connect

I want to interact with my smart contract to use their functions. I am using the `ethereum-react-native-boilerplate` example and I’m trying to execute a smart contract function using the `useWeb3ExecuteFunction` hook. I run this example and its works fine but when I try to interact smart contract with `react-moralis` it's not working and only redirecting to metamask and not calling the function of the smart contract. Below code is called on button click for calling smart contract function.

```
 const ops = {
        contractAddress: "0x878......",
        functionName: "add_data",
        abi: [{"inputs": [{"internalType": "uint256","name": "amount","type": "uint256"},{"internalType": "uint256","name": "total_user","type": "uint256"},{"internalType": "address","name": "token","type": "address"},{"internalType": "string","name": "_value","type": "string"},{"internalType": "string","name": "symbol","type": "string"}],"name": "add_data","outputs": [],"stateMutability": "nonpayable","type": "function"}],
        params: {
          amount: 123333,
          total_user: 6,
          token: "0x34EE........",
          _value: "ABC Coin",
          symbol: "ABC",
        },
      };

      await contractProcessor.fetch({
        params: ops,
        onSuccess: () => {
          console.log("Approval Received");


        },
        onError: (error) => {
   
        },
      });
```

I followed the official documentation of react-moralis
https://github.com/MoralisWeb3/react-moralis#useweb3executefunction

Comment: If you are building an end-user application that interacts with smart contract, I'd recommend 

- Allowing user to bring their own wallet app
- Connect your app to a wallet app using [WalletConnect protocol](https://walletconnect.com/)
- The user can then confirm any smart contract transaction with their wallet - which may also include a hardware wallet devices

Comment: Yes I am already using WalletConnect but whenever I call the useWeb3ExecuteFunction function  It pops up the wallet but the wallet doesn’t show anything

Answer (score 0):

Use Moralis npm module contains for React Native environments.

- `npm i moralis`
- `const Moralis = require('moralis');`